# Why is Pandas interpolate() only finding the middle of my two columns and not being more accurate?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have a table:

```
      -60     -40      -20      0       20      40      60
100   520.0   440.0    380.0   320.0   280.0   240.0   210.0
110   600.0   500.0    430.0   370.0   320.0   280.0   250.0
```

I add the column to the dataframe like so:

```
wind_comp = -35
if int(wind_comp) not in df.columns:
    new_col = df.columns.to_list()
    new_col.append(int(wind_comp))
    new_col.sort()
    df = df.reindex(columns=new_col)
```

Which returns this:

```
      -60   -40  -35   -20    0     20    40    60
100   520   440  NaN   380   320   280   240   210
110   600   500  NaN   430   370   320   280   250
```

I interpolate using pandas interpolate() method like this:

```
df.interpolate(axis=1).interpolate('linear')
```

If I add a new column of say, `-35` it just finds the middle of the `-40` and the `-20` columns and doesn't get any more accurate. So it returns this:

```
      -60     -40     -35     -20      0       20      40      60
100   520.0   440.0   410.0   380.0   320.0   280.0   240.0   210.0
110   600.0   500.0   465.0   430.0   370.0   320.0   280.0   250.0
```

Obviously this row would be correct if I had added a column of `-30`, but I didn't. I need it to give back more accuracy. I want to be able to enter `-13` for example and it give me back that interpolated exact number.

How can I do this? Am I doing something wrong in my code or and I missing something? Please help.

EDIT:

It seems that `pandas.interpolate()` will only halve the to numbers it is placed between and doesn't take into account headers.

I can't find anything that really applies to working with a table using `scipy` but maybe I'm interpreting it wrong. Is it possible to use that or something different?

Comment: `DataFrame.interpolate` doesn't use the headers for anything.  It is linear interpolation, and assumes your columns are evenly spaced.  You need to look into the `scipy.interpolate` functions, where you can pass the headers as your x axis.

Comment: Thank you Tim, can you please help me with how to go about using scipy interpolate please? I'm looking around but am having a hard time finding what I need to apply to my case.  Thank you

Comment: If you give your known x and known y values to `scipy.interpolate.interp1d`, it returns a function.  You give that function an arbitrary x, it returns the interpolated y.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of `interp1d` with your values.  Now, I'm glossing over a huge number of details here, like how to get values from your DataFrame into a list like this.  In many cases, it is easier to do manipulation like this with lists before it becomes a DataFrame.

```
import scipy.interpolate

x =  [   -60,    -40,    -20,     0 ,     20,     40,     60]
y1 = [ 520.0,  440.0,  380.0,  320.0,  280.0,  240.0,  210.0]
y2 = [ 600.0,  500.0,  430.0,  370.0,  320.0,  280.0,  250.0]

f1 = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x,y1)
f2 = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x,y2)

print(-35, f1(-35))
print(-35, f2(-35))
```

Output:

```
-35 425.0
-35 482.5
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, If I were to also interpolate the column on the left hand side and request '103' for example, Is there a way I could have both headers interpolating together? I have expanded the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70562007/how-to-use-interpn-to-interpolate-in-a-dataframe?noredirect=1#comment124734502_70562007

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `scipy.interpolate`?  `interp1d` is designed for 1-D data, but there are several other methods.  I believe `scipy.interpolate.interpolate` will do what you want.